# Does distributional identity for Hermite polynomials imply anything pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

The distributional identity says $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^k k!}e^{-x^2/2-y^2/2}H_k(x)H_k(y)=\delta(x-y)$.

For my understanding, that means for any nice function $g$,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\Big[\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \Big(\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^k k!}e^{-x^2/2-y^2/2}H_k(x)H_k(y)\Big) d y\Big]=g(x)
\end{equation*}

Does it imply anything pointwise about the infinite sum, in particular, can we say that for any $x\neq y$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^k k!}e^{-x^2/2-y^2/2}H_k(x)H_k(y)=0$? (Or, even if it does not imply this, do we know whether the infinite sum above converges to $0$ for $x\neq y$ or not?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel

Comment: But, is the formula valid at $\rho=1$ with a limiting behaviour for the given expression?

Comment: At $\rho\to1$ the function is getting the properties of the delta-function

Comment: I know, but what I'm asking is whether it can be viewed as a pointwise convergence to $0$ for $x\neq y$ or not.